# Polyominoes on a Rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, polyomino, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

Is it possible to obtain a [tetromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) and a [pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) of different colour on each face of a standard 3x3x3 Rubik's cube?

Comment: Too lazy for a full answer, but I did F, X and V pentominoes before.  Z and W are impossible because you can't alternate corners.  The T tetromino is also possible.

Comment: Oops... a tetromino AND a pentomino?  That is different.  I did a single pentomino or single tetromino on a face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic cube pattern that fits this description is:

> The cube-in-a-cube pattern, where each face has a V pentomino and square tetromino:
>  `U L2 D R B' R B' R B' D' L2 U R2 F2 U2`
>  [Link](https://alg.cubing.net/?alg=U_L2_D_R_B-_R_B-_R_B-_D-_L2_U_R2_F2_U2)

A quicker pattern to achieve is this:

> P pentomino, L tetromino on all six faces:
>  `R L U2 F2 R L`
>  [Link](https://alg.cubing.net/?alg=R_L_U2_F2_R_L)

You could also put the U pentomino, T tetromino on a face, but I don't think it is possible to do that on all six faces at the same time.

Comment: Nice work! You may enjoy my next puzzle that I posted.